# Least Squares Method for a sum of functions

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

I would like to use the `curve_fit` function from the `scipy.optimize` module to determine amplitudes, frequencies, phases of sum of sine functions (and one `y0`). It's easy to do when I know a number of sines to use. For example when I know two frequencies from the DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform): `1.152` and `0.432` I can define a function:

```
def func(x, amp1, amp2, freq1 , freq2, phase1, phase2, y0):
    return amp1*np.sin(freq1*x + phase1) + amp2*np.sin(freq2*x + phase2) + y0
```

Then, using the `curve_fit` and constraining intervals of frequencies I can find a good fitting:

```
param, _ = curve_fit(func, t, data, bounds=([-np.inf, -np.inf, 1.14, 0.43, -np.inf, -np.inf, -np.inf], [np.inf, np.inf, 1.16, 0.44, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf]))
```

It looks great:
[image]

But in this case I've prepared the data and I've known a number of frequencies. Do you know how to define the `func` only once and handle all cases (for example five sine functions)? I've tried to put the parameters into lists, e.g. `amp = [amp1, amp2, ... ]` and I've iterated over their length. But there is a problem to define `bounds` for parameter lists. `bounds` is very important to ensure reality model.

The solution does not have to based on `curve_fit`.

Comment: Are you trying to do a [Least-squares spectral analysis (Lomb-Scargle periodogram)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-squares_spectral_analysis)?

Comment: But I can determine the frequencies. I try to find the rest of sine functions parameters. I've read the docs and I don't see how the Lomb-Scargle periodogram can help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the frequencies beforehand the problem is simple. You can set the lower bound to 0 and set the upper bound to 2 * pi * freq for frequency. For amps, set any number (or `np.inf` if you want no boundary).

You can formulate the function in the form `lambda x, amp1, phase1, amp2, phase2... : y`, `curve_fit` can accept a function of undefined number of arguments as long as you supply a proper initial guess.

A sample code for five frequencies:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = np.linspace(0,10,60)
w = [1,2,3,4,5]

a = [1,4,2,3,0.1]
x0 = [0,1,0,1,0.5]

y = np.sum(a_i * np.sin(w_i * x - x0_i) for w_i, a_i, x0_i in zip(w,a, x0))  #base_data
yr = y + np.random.normal(0,0.5, size=x.size)   #noisy data

def func(x, *args):
    """ function of the form lambda x, amp1, phase1, amp2, phase2...."""
    return np.sum(a_i * np.sin(w_i * (x-x0)) for w_i, a_i, x0
                  in zip(w,args[::2], args[1::2]))

ubounds = np.zeros(len(w) * 2)
ubounds[::2] = 10   #setting amp max value to 10 (arbitrary)
ubounds[1::2] = np.asarray(w) * 2 * np.pi
p0 = [0] * 10   # note p0 size
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, yr, p0, bounds=(0, ubounds))
amps, phases = popt[::2], popt[1::2]

plt.plot(x,func(x, *popt))
plt.plot(x,yr, 'go')
```

Comment: Let's summarize. The most important "things" for me are: `*args` argument in the `func(x, *args)` and `p0` argument in the `curve_fit` function indicating a number of used parameters explicitly.

Comment: Yep, your `*args` are the pair of amps, phases for each frequency (which can be 1, 2 or 10, your choice). Your `P0` represents the "seed values" for `curve_fit` optimization, but also it will tell how many parameters you have to optimize: if you don't pass `P0` when you have `*args` in the function definition you'll get an error, as `curve_fit` won't know how many parameters are there to fit.